# How do you count the number of self-referential relationships (that fit certain criteria) in a combined query using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have models that look like this:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID_TYPE, primary_key=True)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID_TYPE, primary_key=True)
    private = db.Column(db.Boolean)

class PostSubscription(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(UUID_TYPE, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user = db.relationship(
        "User", 
        backref=db.backref("subscriptions", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    )
    post_id = db.Column(UUID_TYPE, db.ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    post = db.relationship(
        "Post",
        foreign_keys=[post_id],
        lazy="joined",
        backref=db.backref("subscriptions", cascade="all, delete-orphan"),
    )
    liked = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

I have a query that fetches all of the private `PostSubscription`s which a user has access to, e.g.

```py
query = (db.session.query(PostSubscription)
    .filter(User.id == user_id, Post.private)
    .join(PostSubscription.post)
)
```

I *also* want to fetch the *total* number of likes for the `Post` in the same query (to avoid the N+1 problem). My issue is that these likes are themselves stored in PostSubscription, which is the main thing I'm fetching in the first place. So the whole mess becomes a bit self-referential / circular.

My initial attempt involved adding a property to the `Post` model, but as mentioned above, this solution suffers from the N+1 problem, e.g.

```
@property
def likes(self):
    return db.session.query(PostSubscription).filter_by(
        post_id=self.id, 
        liked=True
    ).count()
```

After a bit of research, I've realized that what I probably need is to use func.count combined with `case`, but I can't figure out how I do this in my particular use case. What I want to do is this:

```py
query = (
    db.session.query(
        PostSubscription,
        func.count(case([Post.subscriptions.liked, Post.id]))
    )
    .filter(User.id == user_id, Post.private)
    .join(PostSubscription.post)
)
```

But that obviously doesn't work because I can't reference a relationship like that. The two tables are already joined, I just don't know how to only get the subscriptions for the `Post` I already have (that is linked to the `PostSubscription`s I am fetching).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following SQLAlchemy query:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased, contains_eager

u = 1
PS1 = aliased(PostSubscription)
PS2 = aliased(PostSubscription)

query = db.session.query(PS1, func.count(PS2.liked))\
    .join(Post, PS1.post_id == Post.id)\
    .join(PS2, PS2.post_id == PS1.post_id)\
    .options(contains_eager(PS1.post))\
    .filter(PS1.user_id == u, Post.private)\
    .group_by(PS1.id)
```

Which should give the following SQL:

```
SELECT post.id AS post_id, 
       post.private AS post_private, 
       postsubscription_1.id AS postsubscription_1_id, 
       postsubscription_1.user_id AS postsubscription_1_user_id, 
       postsubscription_1.post_id AS postsubscription_1_post_id, 
       postsubscription_1.liked AS postsubscription_1_liked, 
       Count(postsubscription_2.liked) AS count_1 
FROM   postsubscription AS postsubscription_1 
       JOIN post ON postsubscription_1.post_id = post.id 
       JOIN postsubscription AS postsubscription_2 ON postsubscription_2.post_id = postsubscription_1.post_id 
WHERE  postsubscription_1.user_id = 1 
       AND post.private = 1 
GROUP  BY postsubscription_1.id
```

Which you could then for example execute and print like this:

```
result = query.all()

for postsubscription, likes in result:
    print(postsubscription, likes)
```

Comment: Thanks! Slight problem though -- the model from my question is a bit oversimplified. An issue I'm now having is that every `Post` also has `Tag`s, which are related with `TagLink` association objects (and backref'd as `tag_links` on the `Post` model). Previously, I had specified this relationship as `lazy="joined"` to avoid N+1, but when I try to use the above query, it's forcing me to exhaustively specify every column on TagLink in the `group_by()` method. I tried to move the join into the query itself (rather than specified in the model) but that hasn't worked. Any thoughts?

Comment: Explicitly, when I try to run the above query, I get this error: `column "tag_links_1.post_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Which I tried to solve by adding `.group_by(..., text("tag_links_1.post_id"))` (need to use the text method as `tag_links` is getting automatically aliased as `tag_links_1`). But when I do that, it just makes me specify all of the columns one at a time. 

If I try `.group_by(..., TagLink)`, it fails as TagLink doesn't map to the alias tag_links_1.

Comment: @acnebs seeing that second comment I'm thinking you could maybe try `contains_eager(PS1.post).contains_eager(Post.tag_links)` in the above query. This (or some similar variation) should hopefully prevent the `tag_links_1` auto alias. Does that get you anywhere?

Comment: The JOIN I tried on the query (to try to avoid that error from `lazy="joined"`) was `.outerjoin(TagLink, Post.id == TagLink.post_id)`. But that does not appear to actually reduce the number of queries being generated by SQLA (with `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True` I'm still seeing a new query for every Tag on each Post).

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat! Didn't realize you could chain the `.contains_eager()` calls like that.